# Best way to interact with I/O bound threads to produce 100 GB random data in C# using TPL

Tags: c#, io, task-parallel-library

I need to produce a 100GB file with random data. I know it's all I/O intensive operation apart from a few lines that are just generating random data.

My target is to create 100 GB or 50 GB files. I tried several approaches:

- Creating Environment.ProcessorCount equivalent threads and assign each of them part of the data (e.g. specific chunk of data)
- I/O bound buffers while holding the data in memory and flush them out to disk during iterations. Refilling them again until the corresponding thread has not done.
- Parallel.For with local storage options. ( This option is described as not the best for I/O bound operations as it is much more effective for in-memory data sets.

All options failed to produce a 100 GB data file with random data. All of them take hours of hours ( i.e. entire half of the day to produce 50 GB )...

**Now Testing the following technique:**

Now I am working on producing individual files for each thread and asking each thread to produce data within those files. This would at least avoid **locking** at the file level.
Then I have planned to merge those files after all threads have finished generating the data in files. But I don't have much hope here too. Reading an individual file that is mega in size and appending its content to another target file might not be right and it could end up producing the same effect. Though here I could do things in a single thread and no need to lock at all.

**Question:**  How to solve this problem in an efficient way?

Comment: A single CPU core can probably produce data faster than your I/O can write it, so parallelization is probably not helpful here.

Comment: You already asked that question, didn't you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write billions of randomly generated data records to a file in most quickest way using TPL in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77104070/how-to-write-billions-of-randomly-generated-data-records-to-a-file-in-most-quick)

Comment: @Fildor: Yeah the conversation goes more in length there. I asked from another perspective here to seek a different point of view.

Comment: @Matthew : If I have single thread, it would be going sequentially and probably for 1000000000 lines, it woudl go to file that many number of times. Why not we create processor number of threads and make all of them at least busy. Thsi way the the record which could process far later because of single thread might get processed earlier by other threads. Is this point of view is not right?

Comment: Totally opinion based (if you don't think @Fildor's comment on being duplicate of your previous Q is right - ideally you would [edit] the question to clarify the difference, but... ) My opinion - just get decent array of fastest SSD drives to match your perf requirements and code in any way you like.

Comment: @Usman I think your line of reasoning is not correct, if a single thread can create data at 10GB/s and your hdd can only write at 0.5GB/s, then having a 2nd thread giving another 10GB/s is not going to help as the bottle neck is your I/O.

Comment: @Mathew: but at least the processing of preparing 10GB data which single thread has to do after writing its first 10GB will be saved. Because the the other threads have already done that. So, at least we first thread release I/O next 10GB was already prepared and will immediately block the I/O for it's 10GB. It's much batter in my opinion in comparison with single thread who's main job to prepare and write to the disk at the same time synchronously.

Answer (score 1):

Create a MemoryMappedFile and allocate 100GB.
After that you can just partition the file and write in blocks.

In your case any memory or CPU optimization is pretty much irrelevant due to I/O bounds of Disk and the underlying connection. A PCIe nVME or M2. SSD will perform the best but I wouldn't recommend writing a 100GB of junk to any solid state drive. HDDs will be slow and if you write to an external Disk connected via USB you'll be even slower.

**In short:** Transfer speed and write speed rule and for big files use a Memory Mapped File for allocation and to prevent joining multiple smaller files.

```
private static void WriteRandom100Gb()
{
    // 100GB file size.
    long size = 100 * (long)Math.Pow(1024, 3);
    string path = "F:\\somebigfile.dat";
    using (var f = File.Create(path))
    {
        using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(f, "bigmmf", size, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite, HandleInheritability.Inheritable, true))
        {

            // 16kB write size.
            long partitionSize = 64 * 1024 * 1024;
            long partitions = (size / partitionSize);

            Random rnd = new Random();

            for (int n = 0; n < partitions; n++)
            {
                using (var mms = mmf.CreateViewStream(n * partitionSize, partitionSize, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Write))
                {
                    byte[] buf = new byte[partitionSize];
                    rnd.NextBytes(buf);
                    mms.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both SSDs and HDDs work best when writing data sequentially. Doing concurrent writes will hurt more than help.

The most trivial implementation I could write took 6 min, 38s to write 82Gb. So if your code takes hours it is likely a huge suboptimization. Contrary to my expectation, the bottleneck is actually in the random number generation, using the built in `Random`. But there might be faster PRNGs depending on your specific needs.

To avoid this we can use multiple threads to generate numbers, but one thread to do the actual writing:

```
var bufferSize = 1024 * 1024 * 64; // 64Mb buffers
var freeBuffers = new ConcurrentBag<byte[]>();
var writeQueue = new BlockingCollection<byte[]>();

void WriteThread()
{
    using var fs = File.OpenWrite(@"c:\temp\randomFile2.bin");
    foreach (var buffer in writeQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        freeBuffers.Add(buffer);
    }
}

var writeTask = Task.Run(WriteThread);

var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
Parallel.For(0,
    1000,
    new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8 },
    () => new Random(), // local init
    (i, state, random) => // loop body
    {
        if (!freeBuffers.TryTake(out var buffer))
        {
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        }
        random.NextBytes(buffer);
        writeQueue.Add(buffer);
        return random;
    },
    random => {} // local finally
    );
writeQueue.CompleteAdding();
writeTask.Wait();
sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"Total Time: {sw.Elapsed}");
```

On my computer this took 53s to generate a 78Gb file. I would assume this is fast enough for most purposes.

Comment: In fact, I am not really relying on numbers. Random number is just one part. It is only generated as a figure and then followed by that a sentence  and then the next line again having a start as random number and then followed by sentence. {randomNumber}.  {sentence}.

Comment: So, I am preparing a large text file for sorting it in the next step using ExternalMergeSort.
Hence, number si not a problem at all.

Comment: One question. All threads (8) are preparing the data in the queue. For 82 GB don't you think you'll get it immediately or later at some point in time OutOfMemoryException? Because all parallel threads could finish their job in a limited time and then they won't get immediately flushed up and you will have some point later when the whole memory gets full. Because 82 GB is in RAM.

Comment: Moreover: you seem generating only 1000 numbers. Because I could see the range you mentioned in the parallel foreach loop

Comment: @Usman it generates 1000 x 64Mb buffers, but adjust the numbers as you see fit. If you are worried about memory you can set a limit on the writeQueue, that way the producer threads will block if the write thread cannot keep up. But the main point is that concurrent writes is counterproductive. If generating numbers is fast enough, just write a simple loop.